# Sharepoint 2010 Client OM - How to get the Last approved document version?

Tags: client-object-model

I am trying to use sharepoint foundation 2010 as file store for a website. Every document update must go thru an approval cycle and finally gets to a approved status to show up on the website for end users. When a document is updated in sharepoint the status is reset to "Draft" even if the previous version was approved. This is the intended behavior.

File.Versions gives me the list of versions.

How to get the version that was last "Approved"?

Comment: By Client OM do you mean C# OM or rahter Javascript OM? The JS OM does not allow to my knowledge Versions access, rather through the use of SOAP Web Services

Answer (score 1):

If you loop through the File.Versions you can find the one with the IsCurrentVersion property set to true. That should be the most recently approved version.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fileversion_members(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code and this will give latest approved version.

```
SPList oList = new SPSite("http://developerBOX1").AllWebs["Web1"].GetList(
                    "http://developerBOX1/Web1/DocLIB");
SPListItemCollection collListItems = oList.Items;
SPListItem itemFound;
if (oList.EnableVersioning){
    foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
{
SPListItemVersionCollection allVersions = oListItem.Versions;          
// Iterate through all versions         
foreach (SPListItemVersion version in allVersions){
    if (version.Level == SPFileLevel.Published){
        itemFound = version.ListItem;
        return;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks.. trying to find SPListItem in CLOM. is this from Webservices by any chance??

Comment: hi bhuvan the CLOM encapsulates sharepoint webservices and gives you a ease of use API

Comment: You can write this code in a web service and use this services in your website. I hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Bhuvan, Will this solution help you in your requirment, Please let me know?

Comment: Thanks Yogi.. My problem is that I cannot find the SPList class in CLOM. List class in CLOM doesn't contain Versions property. Can you guide me on how to use this code on the client side. Thanks

Comment: Hi Bhuvan, you can write this code in webpart or class library, might be i am not understanding your requirment, if this is the case plaese share your requirment in business term or what eaxctly you want to do and i will be more happy to help you.

Comment: The confusion is that the question specified the use of the Client Object Model (CSOM) and the answer given shows code from the Server Object Model.